# Isolated result in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I want to generate a series of buttons that call a function and I want to return only to the caller button div.

Now I have:

```
  app.directive("phone", function () {
      return {
        scope: {
          dial: "&"
        },

       template: '<input type="text" ng-model="value"> <div class="button" ng-click="dial({message:value})">prova!   </div> {{ $parent.pippo }}',
        };
    });
```

---

```
<div ng-app="phoneApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div phone dial="callHome(message)"> </div><br><br>
```

and

```
          $scope.callHome = function (message) {
            $scope.pippo = "casa";
          };
```

How can i isolate the response to the caller button?

Comment: You want to isolate `pippo` property from parent `$scope` ?

Comment: Hi Apperiron, i don't know how solve my problem :D  I want realize this situation:

BUTTON1   RESULT1

BUTTON2   RESULT2

ecc.. when i click on button 1, it call a function and return its result only to the caller div...

Answer (score 0):

Assign `controller` and `controllerAs` for your directive so you will be able to create new directive for each button with separate **contex**:

```js
app.directive("phone", function () {
  function PhoneDirectiveCtrl ($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
  }
  
  PhoneDirectiveCtrl.prototype.dial = function () {
    this.pippo = this.message + 'casa';
  }
  
  var tempalte = '<input type="text" ng-model="value"> <div class="button" ng-click="ctrl.dial()">prova!</div> {{ ctrl.pippo }}';
  
  return {
    controller: PhoneDirectiveCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    scope: {
      message: '@'
    },
    template: template
  }
});
```

Do not use `$scope` of parent when you have to create few instances of same `directive`.

P.S. Do not define methods related to directive only at `$parent` controller. You **should** create dedicated `controller` with dedicated methods that called by your `directive`

Comment: Thank you so much to help me! the code snippet don't run beacause app is not defined. can you modify the code snippet? Can give me an html example? i'm new of angularJs.  Finally...how can assign you some stars to your response?

Comment: Can you create a simple example? 

if in html page i want 3 button that when pressed return  the value of this function

scope.b = function(){
                  return 4;
                };

how can i solve?